# When my driveway gate opens (powered by 12v battery) i want a light to illuminate the driveway for safety

Tags: switch, light, low-voltage

Is there a switch that can turn on the 110v lights?

Comment: Not knowing the layout, so this is a general suggestion.  Have you considered a motion activated light?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Do you have a wiring diagram for your driveway gate opener?

Answer (score 2):

What I think that you might be after is called a relay. A relay is an electrically operated switch. It takes a low voltage signal to switch a higher voltage, so instead of you physically flipping a light switch, the switcher in your case would be the power to the gate. When the gate receives power the the relay receives power and 'flips' the switch.

Comment: Yes, a RIBU1C is readily available, UL *listed* (not just component recognized!), and fits the application well

Comment: Niggling detail - the type of relay applicable to THIS question is *"takes a low voltage signal to switch a higher voltage"* - relays ALSO come in many OTHER configurations suited to other applications...

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I know right after I posted that I was going to take a hit on it (all good). Tis 100% true

Answer (score 0):

A relay with 12V coil like a [finder 62](https://gfinder.findernet.com/public/attachments/62/EN/S62EN.pdf)-829-012-xxxx, this particoular is handy because it requires fastons and not a specific docking.
In any case my suggestion is to check on your garage door ECU if there's an auxiliary contact (usually there are) exactly for this purpose.

Comment: I don't see any supportable way to mount that relay, though.

Comment: Yeah, those relays are Rather Useless to folks in the USA (UL Component Recognized)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica just add fastons to the wires and enclose it in a junction box. Other models require din-rail but as far as I know in the it's not as common as it's here.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I think you shoul research a little, all those relays are UL rated, just check here: https://www.findernet.com/sites/default/files/2017-06/Finder%20UL%20Cert.pdf

Comment: @DDS -- no, *you* need to research a little, that cRUus at the top of the page means that those relays are UL *Component Recognized*, which means that UL needs to re-examine their use in a finished product, instead of just putting them out there for anyone electrically qualified to install however the directions permit

Comment: The Eel is right about the RU mark.  Having one of those flappy-dappying inside a junction box is a recipe for, at the very least, getting written up.  Your jurisdiction may vary.